# Passing variable from Custom class to Fragment (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, fragment

I'm currently working with android for my project and I can't figure out the way to passing variable from Custom class to Fragment. I can exchange variable between MainActivity and Fragment but I can't use the same way to do it in Custom class and Fragment.

The way that I use to send variable between MainActivity and Fragment is something like this

In Fragment file:

```js
public class FourthFragment extends Fragment {

    MainActivity activity;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    }
```

and after that I can use any methods from MainActivity in my Fragment.It's work fine! So I try to do the same way to passing variable from Custom class to Fragment but it's didn't work out.

The code that I tried.
This is my Custom Class (MyAdapter.java)

```js
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        MainActivity activity;



        FourthFragment fourthfragment = new FourthFragment();



        private ArrayList<CreateList> galleryList;
            private Context context;





        public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CreateList> galleryList) {
                this.galleryList = galleryList;
                this.context = context;
            }

            @Override
            public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cell_layout, viewGroup, false);
                return new ViewHolder(view);
            }




        @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
                viewHolder.title.setText(galleryList.get(i).getImage_title());
                viewHolder.img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                viewHolder.img.setImageResource((galleryList.get(i).getImage_ID()));

            viewHolder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        builder1.setMessage("Are you sure you want to send this "+ galleryList.get(i).getImage_title());
                        builder1.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Toast.makeText(context,"Yes",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                                //TODO: Problem here NULL pointer exception


                                fourthfragment.imgSend();

                            }
                        });
                        builder1.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Toast.makeText(context,"No",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                        builder1.show();
                        Toast.makeText(context,"Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }




            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return galleryList.size();
            }

            public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
                private TextView title;
                private ImageView img;
                public ViewHolder(View view) {
                    super(view);

                    title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                    img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
                }
            }
        }
```

And This one is my Fragment (FourthFragment.java) I only cut some parts of it that important.

```js
public class FourthFragment extends Fragment {

        MainActivity activity;
        MyAdapter myAdapter;
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        byte[] dataOut2 = {(byte)255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0};

    @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            init(savedInstanceState);

            if (savedInstanceState != null)
                onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
              }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fourth, container, false);
            initInstances(rootView, savedInstanceState);
            return rootView;
        }

        private void init(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Init Fragment level's variable(s) here
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("UnusedParameters")
        private void initInstances(View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Init 'View' instance(s) with rootView.findViewById here
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageGallery);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),2);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            ArrayList<CreateList> createLists = prepareData();
            MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), createLists);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }



       //Below this is a method that I create to recieve variable(i) from Custom Class (MyAdapter.java)

        public void imgSend(int i)
        {
            if( i< 28)
            {
                dataOut2[8] = (byte)1;
                int j = 0;
                j = i + 1;
                dataOut2[9] = (byte)j;
                activity.sendMessage(dataOut2);
            }
            else if(i>=28)
            {
                dataOut2[8] = (byte)2;
                int k = 0;
                k = i - 27;
                dataOut2[9]= (byte)k;
                activity.sendMessage(dataOut2);
            }
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),""+dataOut2,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

And when I run all the program its caused a problem like this 
when I start to click 'Yes' in Dialog that start to do a method
    fourthFragment.imgSend(i);

```js
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: myapplication.example.com.botcontrol, PID: 22397
                                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void myapplication.example.com.botcontrol.MainActivity.sendMessage(byte[])' on a null object reference
                                                                                          at myapplication.example.com.botcontrol.Fragment.FourthFragment.imgSend(FourthFragment.java:156)
                                                                                          at myapplication.example.com.botcontrol.Fragment.MyAdapter$1$1.onClick(MyAdapter.java:70)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:157)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6939)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

So what can I do or any other way to send the variable? If anything else is needed, I will post it!
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's because you cast the context to MainActivity, you need to be more general in this case. Use just Activity for the variable. And check the type before casting it.

```
Activity activity;

...

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if(getActivity() instanceOf MainActivity){
        activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    } else if(getActivity() instanceOf CustomActivity){
        activity = (CustomActivity) getActivity();
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason that I use MainActivity because I put all the methods that connecting with Bluetooth in there and called those method by Fragment to sending variable to outside. Is it going to be fine if I change it to Activity?

Comment: Sorry i was sleepy last night and confuse where you should be more general.

Comment: Why two `if()`s if you can use `||` to merge conditions?

Comment: No, you can't because each if has a different result, and i don't know for how many Custom Activities he want to use this, so he know who to make this for N Activities.

Answer (score 0):

Your `activity` variable is null. Have you committed the fragment? I don't see a place in your code that you do that.

A fragment is committed and attached to its activity using the `FragmentManager`. Typically, you will commit a fragment in `Activity.onCreate()`, but you can also commit elsewhere depending on your use case.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.my_fragment_container, new FourthFragment()).commitNow();
    }

}
```

Once your Fragment is committed and attached, you shouldn't get a null pointer exception anymore.

[For reference, here's the documentation related to attaching fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding)